# find jsPlumb connection between

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

I have this JS

http://jsfiddle.net/xzf0ffcu/18/

```
jsPlumb.ready(function() {
```

How can I find out whitch element is connected with whitch, can I console.log something like #div1 connected with #div4, #div2 with #div5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you have your console.log() in your jsfiddle.

Replace it with:

```
console.log("connection", i.sourceId , i.targetId);
```